# How do I disable source maps in Safari?

Tags: safari

The version of Safari shipped with Mavericks (7.0) includes support for Source maps which I thought would be a blessing for Coffeescript development. Unfortunately I'm finding that much like Chrome, they don't work very well. Breakpoints rarely get hit and so I'd like to turn this feature off.

I can't find an option for this. Am I stuck with them on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround for locally distributed vendor js files would be to edit them and modify the reference to the source map.  For instance on backbone.min.js I've altered the line

```
//# sourceMappingURL=backbone-min.map
```

to

```
//# source MappingURL=backbone-min.map
```

...so that I can easily switch it back on again by removing the space.  Obviously if you're using a CDN version this isn't going to work, but for development I'd recommend using local copies of vendor libs.